# Alignment of autogenerate mail using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any possible way to align the auto generate mail while upload a file to server. It sends the mail to admin what we upload in server like this

> Hi All,
>   We have uploaded the following files onto FTP site. Details
>   are as below:
>
> File name                          File size
>
> D:\New folder\diff2.zip               172

I want to align this one in proper manner anyone help to resolve this..

Comment: You can send email body as a html text with any formatting. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: In that link they mentioning header alone apart from nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Well you can save you email template in HTML file and Replace Tag after reading it.. E.g for above create the HTML as you want and then Replace the [[PATH]] Tag before sending email.

see [this](http://martinnormark.com/generate-html-e-mail-body-in-c-using-templates)  thread it may be help full for you.

Thanks